# wso2is org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager Source code

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Would you please share the git repo url where i can download the source code for this class:
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager

I am on WSO2 5.2.0 IS server.

I need to understand the framework before i can make any changes to my custom user store.

-Raj

Comment: Have you tried googling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clone https://github.com/wso2/carbon4-kernel repo and checkout  to 4.4.x branch. 5.2.0 released tag is 4.4.9

Comment: Thanks for quicker response.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `https://github.com/biliroy/carbon4-kernel/blob/master/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/core/jdbc/JDBCUserStoreManager.java`

It´s a forked code from `https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel`